# Compiler doesn't generate a field for implicit val when an implicit val with the same type is present in the superclass

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.11

I have a class `Foo` defined as follows:

```
class Elem[A]

abstract class BaseDef[T](implicit val selfType: Elem[T])

case class Foo[A, T]()(implicit val eA: Elem[A], val eT: Elem[T]) extends BaseDef[A]
```

To my surprise, `getDeclaredFields` does *not* include `eA`:

```
object Test extends App {
  private val fields = classOf[Foo[_, _]].getDeclaredFields

  println(fields.mkString("\n"))
  assert(fields.exists(_.getName == "eA"))
}
```

produces

```
private final scalan.Elem scalan.Foo.eT    
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:151)
    at scalan.Test$.delayedEndpoint$scalan$Test$1(JNIExtractorOps.scala:15)
    at scalan.Test$delayedInit$body.apply(JNIExtractorOps.scala:11)
```

Is there an explanation for this or is this a known bug (Scala version is 2.11.7)? I *can* access `eA` from outside the class.

It seems the compiler decides it can reuse `selfType` field for `eA`, which would be great if it didn't break access to `eA` in scala-reflect.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in REPL, `scala> classOf[collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder.ofRef[_]].getDeclaredFields
res0: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private final scala.reflect.ClassTag scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofRef.evidence$2, `

Comment: The problem happens with a specific class. If it happened always, it would be noticed long ago. I'll try to minimize it tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I see. I can reproduce it when class extends one with implicit value argument, as with `class BaseDef[T](implicit val s: Elem[T])`. **val** is crucial

Comment: Yes, I've just minimized the example as well.

Comment: Btw, `case` class, `implicit` keyword, and secondary parameter list in `Foo` are not necessary to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reply from Jason Zaugg on scala-user](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/uv9yZgDrvpQ/lcwQomd5BAAJ):

> The compiler avoids redundant fields in subclasses if it statically determines that the value is stored in a field in a super class that exposes it via an accessible accessor.
>
> To prevent this, you might be able to change the superclass constructor by removing the val keyword and add another val to that class that stores the parameter.